# How to determine the visual properties of a specific steel compound?

Tags: metal, materials, metallurgy

The material that is described in a paper by Li *et. al.*<sup>[1]</sup> is interesting to me, but they don't go into any details on what the end result would look like visually. Out of curiosity, I was wondering if there was any way to determine these properties.

As an extremely brief summary of the relevant part of the paper, the material in question is stainless steel sintered with copper-coated graphene.
Additional details that may be important:
Gr-Cu is first produced in sheets and then ball-milled and added to the stainless steel up to 0.2 percentage by weight.

I am also aware that the color of most types of steel can be somewhat controlled based on heat or chemical treatment, but I'm not sure if those options would be be viable for this kind of material.

#### References:

1. Li, Z.; Ni, H.; Chen, Z.; Ni, J.; Chen, R.; Fan, X.; Li, Y.; Yuan, Y. Enhanced tensile properties and corrosion resistance of stainless steel with copper-coated graphene fillers. *Journal of Materials Research and Technology* **2020,** *9* (1), 404–412. [DOI: 10.1016/j.jmrt.2019.10.069](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmrt.2019.10.069).

Comment: Better asking in Physics SE unless there is an advanced Optics SE site. I think you have no chance to get an answer, btw.

Comment: I could try wording it as a request for wavelength reflectivity and absorption spectrum, but I suspect they would just tell me to ask here since it's in relation to the results of mixing metallic compounds. I'll agree that I'm probably not going to get an answer though.